# Есть ли разница при определении переменной в стеке?

Tags: c++

Есть ли разница между:

```cpp
vector<int> vec();
```

и

```cpp
vector<int> vec = vector<int>();
```

Просто у меня intellisense работает только во втором случае, потому я всегда его использовал, но хочу знать имеет ли это последствия.

Comment: Важно отметить, что класс `std::vector` хранит данные там, где их разместит переданный ему аллокатор. Так как обычно никто аллокатор не передает, используется простое размещение на куче.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первое объявляет функцию с именем `vec` с сигнатурой `(void) -> vector<int>` (most vexing parse), второе страдает от копипасты. Правильно делать так `vector<int> vec{};`

Comment: действительно. facepam.

Comment: правильно делать так `vector<int> vec;` скобки не нужны в этом случае

Comment: @KoVadim Опускать скобки имеет смысл только в ситуациях, когда есть намерение оставить переменную потенциально неинициализированной, а не вообще во всех таких ситуациях.

Comment: в данном случае вектор вполне себе будет инициализирован.

Comment: @KoVadim Смысл не в том, что он остался бы неинициализированным, а в том, что удобно, когда присутствие {} означает инициализацию, а их отсутствие - отсутствие инициализации.

Comment: то есть, `std::vector<int> vec;` не будет инициализирован?

Comment: @KoVadim Он будет инициализирован в любом случае, но понять, что объект инициализирован, а не заполнен мусором проще по наличию {}, чем выясняя тип переменной и вспоминая, имеется ли у этого типа нетривиальный конструктор по-умолчанию.

Comment: + может быть полезно в шаблонах

Answer (score 2):

В первом случае Вы объявляете функцию vec:) -это известная проблема в с++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

можно просто писать

```
vector<int> vec;
```

работать будет хорошо и правильно.